# Login registration that redirects to different page according to user type in django

Tags: django

I am creating  login registration in djanog. and I am unable to redirect login based on different usertype. If any example could be given it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us, what you have done so far in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and you'll get help
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

in ur urls.py file

```
 from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
 urlpatterns =[
     path('login/',LoginView.as_view(template_name='ur .HTML',name='login')     
   ]
```

in ur HTML FILE:-

```
 <form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>
```

if u want to redirect to login page when any AnonymusUser tries to then in ur  project's SETTINGS.py file:----

```
 LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

if u want to redirect FROM login page after login-in:---
in ur settings.py file:----

```
 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'name of the url u want to redirect'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own LoginView by inheriting from

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
```

and then you need to override the function

```
def get_success_url(self)
```

so your LoginView will be like

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

CustomLoginView(LoginView):

    def get_success_url(self):
       if self.user.type = 'USER_TYPE':
          return 'YOUR_CUSTOM_URL'
```

then you need to appoint your created login view in URL

```
 path('login/',CustomLoginView.as_view(template_name='ur .HTML',name='login')
```